# RewriteRule замена вида ссылки

Tags: .htaccess, php

Нужно заменить ссылку в `.htaccess`.

Ссылка вида `site.ru/download/**1**`.

Преобразовать в

```
site.ru/go/load.php?id=**1**
```

Делаю так:

```
RewriteRule ^download\/(.*)$ /go/load.php?id=$1
```

Вроде, правильно, но скрипт не ловит айдишник, а значит неправильно.

Comment: Эм, всё правильно должно быть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лишний слэш перед go